# Rails rake db:schema:load failing to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to do `rake db:schema:load` but am encountering an error and it seems the problem is with the `enable_extension("pg_repack")` step:

```
rake db:schema:load --trace
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
**************************************************
⛔️ WARNING: Sidekiq testing API enabled, but this is not the test environment.  Your jobs will not go to Redis.
**************************************************
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:schema:load
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.2005s
-- enable_extension("pg_repack")
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/share/postgresql/extension/pg_repack.control": No such file or directory
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pg_repack"
...
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
```

I'm using postgres 9.6.6:

```
which postgres
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin/postgres
```

Any idea how I can get `pg_repack` to work?

EDIT:

When running `pgxn install pg_repack` I get this:

```
INFO: best version: pg_repack 1.4.3
INFO: saving /var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmp02_KE6/pg_repack-1.4.3.zip
INFO: unpacking: /var/folders/7d/xvqc5yxs10n6206lytrbs9wm0000gn/T/tmp02_KE6/pg_repack-1.4.3.zip
INFO: building extension
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include -DREPACK_VERSION=1.4.3 -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/internal -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pg_repack.o pg_repack.c
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include -DREPACK_VERSION=1.4.3 -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/internal -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgut/pgut.o pgut/pgut.c
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include -DREPACK_VERSION=1.4.3 -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/internal -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgut/pgut-fe.o pgut/pgut-fe.c
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2 pg_repack.o pgut/pgut.o pgut/pgut-fe.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib -lpq -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs   -lpgcommon -lpgport -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lreadline -lm -o pg_repack
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -DREPACK_VERSION=1.4.3 -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/internal -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o repack.o repack.c
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -DREPACK_VERSION=1.4.3 -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/include/internal -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o pgut/pgut-spi.o pgut/pgut-spi.c
awk '/^[^#]/ {printf "_%s\n",$1}' exports.txt >exports.list
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -bundle -multiply_defined suppress -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -o pg_repack.so repack.o pgut/pgut-spi.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs   -bundle_loader /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin/postgres
sed 's,REPACK_VERSION,1.4.3,g' pg_repack.sql.in > pg_repack--1.4.3.sql;
sed 's,REPACK_VERSION,1.4.3,g' pg_repack.control.in > pg_repack.control
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
INFO: installing extension
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin'
/usr/bin/install -c  pg_repack '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/bin'
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib'
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/share/postgresql@9.6/extension'
/bin/sh /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/share/postgresql@9.6/extension'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755  pg_repack.so '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/lib/pg_repack.so'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//pg_repack.control '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/share/postgresql@9.6/extension/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644  pg_repack--1.4.3.sql pg_repack.control '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.6/share/postgresql@9.6/extension/'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `install'.
```

But when I run `psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_repack" tr_dev` I still get this message:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/share/postgresql/extension/pg_repack.control": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error says that pg_repack doesn't exists. First check your directory to see if pg_repack is there if it is but the error still persists you can try

Remove pg_repack using DROP EXTENSION pg_repack or just dropping the repack schema.

1) download a new pg_repack extension from

[pg repack download](https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_repack/)

2) `$ pgxn install pg_repack`

3) `$ cd pg_repack
    $ make
    $ sudo make install`

4) After installation, load the pg_repack extension in the database you want to process. pg_repack is packaged as an extension, so you can execute:

`$ psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION pg_repack" -d your_database`

Comment: Do you know the best way to install pgxn? It doesn't look like that's currently installed on my mac.

Comment: Understood you have a mack. Search inside link I gave to you how to install on your mac t

Comment: Got it! I got pgxn installed and installing pg_repack seemed to work I think? I included the output as the CREATE EXTENSION step is still failing.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem has to do with having postgres installed via homebrew but also running it via the Postgres app. It seems like the pgxn is installing pg_repack into the homebrewed install version of the app.